How can I make my Apple Magic Trackpad 2 work well with Ubuntu 24.04 as it did in Ubuntu 22.04?
After upgrading from Ubuntu 22 to 24 on my two machines, I am unable to effectively use an Apple Magic Trackpad 2.
Computer details:

Lenovo ThinkStation P620: Ubuntu 24.04.1, Gnome 46, X11, Linux 6.8.0-49-generic
Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 8: Ubuntu 24.04.1, Gnome 46, Wayland, Linux 6.5.0-1025-oem

Observations (video evidence):

Unexpected: Moving my finger along the trackpad surface at a slow/normal speed does not move my cursor, but moving it very fast (uncontrollably) does move the cursor.
Expected: Moving my finger while pressing the trackpad (to trigger a drag) works perfectly fine at any speed.
Expected: I have no issues with moving the cursor when using a mouse.

I have tested and observed this issue using 2 machines running Ubuntu 24.04, 2 different Magic Trackpads 2, and 2 different USB↔Lightning cables. In earlier versions of Ubuntu (including 22.04), I had no issues using an Apple Magic Trackpad 2. As a fan of 3-finger-dragging, I installed this patched version of libinput after encountering the issue above, and that also had no impact on or resolution of the problem.
How can I fix this, or start to troubleshoot it?
